# Spring MVC form:checkbox not working

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc, checkbox, binding

I am having an issue with the Spring `form:checkbox` tag.

I currently have a JSP page with a `form:checkbox` tag bound to a Java `boolean` field. When I put a tick in the checkbox and submit the form the value is `false`.

Here is the checkbox on my JSP:

```
<form:checkbox id="field_termsandconditions" path="agreeTermsAndConditions" />
```

My `GET` controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page1.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPage(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("MyObject", new MyObject());
    return getURL(request);
}
```

My `POST` controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page1.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processPage(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    ModelMap model,
    MyObject myObject,
    BindingResult bindingResult) {

        System.out.println(myObject.isAgreeTermsAndConditions);
}
```

`myObject.isAgreeTermsAndConditions` is always `false` when it hits the `POST` controllers even when checked!

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know how spring-mvc works, but in HTML checkboxes have string values of ON or OFF, so you need a mapping from the string values to boolean.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late to answer, but maybe it will help some other person.

When you auto-generate getter and setters for boolean values it is very often generated without 'is' prefix.

For instance, in the case mentioned above the generated setter for 'isAgreeTermsAndConditions' property might be the following: 'setAgreeTermsAndConditions()', note there is no 'is' prefix in the method. The same true for the getters as well.

Since property getter and setters names are used find and bind to the model property, the checkbox might be not shown on the UI or not working properly if there are property name and getters/setters mismatch.

Make sure the property 'isAgreeTermsAndConditions' has the following getters/setters method names: getIsAgreeTermsAndConditions()/setIsAgreeTermsAndConditions(...)